# Screen capture software for Microsoft Windows with a time limit

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I am looking for a screen capture software for Microsoft Windows with a time limit, i.e. that could set to record for the next X minutes.

Any license and price is fine.

(my use case: [download an Adobe connect recorded meeting when not the host](https://superuser.com/q/1298687/116475)).